# Multiple loaders concurrently

Tags: android, contacts

I need to load data from Contacts.Content_URI and Data.Contents_URI concurrently.
With a code like this I may start different loaders alternatively.

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    switch (loader.getId()) {
        case 0:
            // do some stuff here
            break;
        case 1:
            // do some other stuff here
            break;
        case 2:
            // do some more stuff here
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I tried with no result to start 2 loaders concurrently against different Content_URI. Is this possible?

Comment: what exact data do you want to retrieve?

Comment: My probleme is a little more articulated than my question but to not bore too much in the forum I am trying to understand if it is possible to do what I asked, to find my way with a few attempts. The mine may be not the better way but testing , sometimes, may be usefull to learn. For knowledge I renew my question if it is possible to start 2 loaders concurrently against different data source because in 1 week of research I found no answer. Now, very summary, what I need is to retrieve is DISPLAY_NAME from Contacts.CONTENT_URI and GIVEN_NAME from Data.CONTENT_URI for a ListView of all contacts.

Comment: ok si what happens if you call initLoader with different ids two times one by one?

Comment: already tested. it crash. this is why i am not sure it is possible.

Comment: no. sorry. I tested another way. I mess initLoader with 2 different ids. I try now

Comment: I'm turning in a circle. In the onCreateLoader calling 2 Cursorloaders do not give error but I may return only 1 at a time

Comment: if you call initLoader twice onCreateLoader wull be called twice as well

Comment: @pskink. I was offline. I did some try with no success. I am not able to find enough information on how to call twice onCreateLoader. For now I get only errors. I'll do some other attents but I found no documentation.

Comment: Nothing. I am not able to implement twice concurrentely onCreateLoader.
Untill someone show me that it is possible I assume that is not possible because I found no exemples on this case. But i find it hard that I am the first that try to do this. I search another way.